# Link mono in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, mono

I am trying to embed the mono runtime in a C++ OS X console app (Will be used for scripting logic in a home-brew game engine, much like Unity3D). I am using XCode as the IDE and am failing spectacularly at linking the mono libraries. I come from the dark side (Windows) and am new to mac libraries and XCode.

I have successfully built mono and referenced the header folder but get a slew of APPLE-MOCH-O linkers errors no matter what .a I add to the project. I have also successfully built this sample project https://github.com/inkdev/Embedded-Mono-Sample for windows. The mono site on the topic http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono is confusing and of little use to me.

Help would be hugely appreciated.

EDIT:
If I remember correctly, I followed these commands http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_on_OSX and got the source from here: https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mono, and used make and make install. I added the /mono/include... folder to XCode's "Header Search Path" and that resolved all the unfound includes. Under /mono/lib/ I have tried several different *.dynlib files ( drag them into XCode ) but none have worked. libmono-2.0.1.dylib says "..file was built for unsupported file format..", and libmonoboehm-2.0.dylib simply says "...Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64..."

Comment: Please explain exactly how you're linking and the errors you get.

Comment: Hi Rolf, I have updated my question with some more info. Thank you ahead of time for the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: So, after adding more info and looking back at the http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_on_OSX I tried compiling for AMD64 and that seems to have worked :) I now have runtime errors, but it compiles and links. This is also my first Stack Overflow question, what should I do with it? Just delete it?

Comment: Just ad answer yourself and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To anyone in the future who wants to compile and link the Mono runtime in XCode, here are the steps I followed.

- Grab/Extract the latest *.tar.gz from: http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/
- Follow these instructions: http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_on_OSX
- Open up `/mono` and drag `/mono/lib/libmono-X.X.dylib` into your XCode project ( Make sure it is adde to target ).
- In XCode, select your project, select your target, select Build Settings.
- Search for "Header Search Paths" and add: `/mono/include/mono-X.X`
- Use this source code to test it out: https://github.com/inkdev/Embedded-Mono-Sample
- You may need to copy `/mono/etc/mono/X.X` to `/mono` to fix a runtime error.

All your monos are belong to us now, enjoy.

Comment: Mono Project actually has a page about embedding mono in projects. I would start there (although Alec's answer is valuable for Conceptual Test). Ideally you would want to install Mono on OS X or have it and associated libraries as part of your application.